# What is the meaning of "GET THE LOOK" in the following example?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

We are translating Samsung's copy for a new device into several languages.

The copy contains the expression "GET THE LOOK" in several places.

"With designer cases and a fully customizable Window, XXX makes it easy to match your phone to your style. GET THE LOOK Take selfies from a whole new angle. Snap selfies with any of your cameras, then edit and share..."

Comment: It's meaningless advertising babble. I suggest you translate it into equally meaningless advertising babble in other languages.

Comment: "to get the look [of something]" is quite informal English. It means "to match the appearance/style [of something].  It can also mean "to appear stylish". Depends on context.

Comment: It's also a bit dated as far as 'pop slang' goes. It was popularised in the 80s by [Prince - U got the Look](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jCuroTbqBI)

Comment: A modeling agency, say, might be on the lookout for a model who has "the look". Whatever that might mean to them at any given time, it will be some *distinctive*  or *striking* quality that the person's appearance embodies.

Answer (score 1):

'Look' as a noun can mean a particular style or fashion, or the appearance of someone or something specific.

It's not clear from your quotation whether it applies to the first part about phone cases, or to the second part about taking selfies, but "the look" is such a generic and flexible expression that it could apply to either! It could mean that your phone case will help you get your phone to look the way you want it to. It could also mean you want your photographs to look a certain way and that this phone app will give you the tools to achieve 'the look' you want.

Context is key, because on its own this expression is meaningless. It is often said in a 'knowing' way - ie you expect your audience to know what you mean.